# I want single field should equally distributed on all over the form in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a table having only one field say "Program Name", I wanted to change around is the format of the screen. Like since all the programs are in a line on the left side, the right side of the screen is very empty. Is it possible to make the programs I add add in this format instead? Please in following image.

[image]

I want result like like given in below image, and please note that I have only one field in table and hence in form. Therefore, I want to put this single field data Horizontally instead vertically.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following ways to achieve that:

1. The easy way: Detach the form from table and make unbound ListBox with RowSource of that table.
2. Detach the form from the table, add TabControl with a lot of Tabs, make them invisible. When form is opened - read table, assign captions to Tabs and make them visible.
3. If records in that table changed rarely, detach form from table, and write VBA code that opens form in designer mode and add/delete/rename controls, that you choose to show records from table (buttons for example).
4. If records in that table changed often and may be various for various users. Detach form from table, put there WebView control, and fill it by VBA code. (don't forget to use WithEvents to catch click events from inner HTML).

Comment: All these ways i did see in the wild... and used by myself. But i suppose you should use number 1.

Comment: I have tried the first method but it is not showing the way I posted earlier. It showing just simple with values like test1, test2, test3, test4

Comment: @aiseries, yes, but now you can use free space on the right of `ListBox`